# Set the style programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I created a custom TabLayout for my viewpage 2 and everything works fine. But I don't know how to programmatically make the text of the tabs lowercase (except for the first letter). I found a way that you can create your own style and set textAllCaps = false and pass it to the constructor. I did as follows:

```
class CustomTabLayout : TabLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context, 
        attrs,
        R.style.m_tab_layout_style
    )
}
```

And I call so:

```
val mTabLayout = CustomTabLayout(this, null, R.style.m_tab_layout_style)
```

But it doesn't work and I found information that starting from android 5 it is not possible to pass a style after constructing a view. And the correct way to solve this problem is to pass to a 4-argument constructor, for example,

```
RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this, null, 0, R.style.MyRelativeLayout);
```

But TabLayout does not have a fourth defStyleRes argument, and who can tell me how to pass the style for TabLayout programmatically or how to make the TabLayout tab text lowerCase programmatically (except for the first letter).